# Unable to locate the specified class: Hooks.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Codeigniter web application working good in my localhost,  but in live server i am getting error **Unable to locate the specified class: Hooks.php**

In my localhost
application\config\hooks.php is empty file and 
application\config\config.php setting $config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

How to solve? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enabling Hooks**

The hooks feature can be globally `enabled/disabled` by setting the following item in the `application/config/config.php file:`

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

**Defining a Hook**

Hooks are defined in the `application/config/hooks.php file.` Each hook is specified as an array with this prototype:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'MyClass',
        'function' => 'Myfunction',
        'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
);
```

Also take reference from [Hooks](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: CLASS-The class that you wish to invoke, if it is procedural code leave it as blank.
FUNCTION-The function name you wish to call.
FILENAME-The file name containing your class/function.
FILEPATH-Location of the hook file.
PARAMS-Additional parameter if needed it is optional

Comment: why i can't keep $config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE; in live server? but its working in localhost and test server!!!

Comment: hope this url help you http://codefury.net/2009/11/enable-site-wide-profiling-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to some missing file. Lots of answers are regarding Sessions and stuff.
I had my application working perfectly and suddenly this error occurred. I re-uploaded my applications folder and everything is back in order.